# inner product space in Euclidean space.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

[image]

I dont quite understand the solution. why symmetric property prove this question?

Comment: I think it is just so that symmetry property would hold in order for this to be an inner product

Comment: I don't think they are claiming that that parenthetic note is a complete proof.  They are just commenting that the result will depend on the symmetry of the matrix.  Presumably when you show that the associated product is symmetric.  And they are suggesting that the same argument will go through for any symmetric matrix.